# Replicating Heroku's Review Apps on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, heroku, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I'm currently working for a client that are using Heroku and migrating to AWS. However, we're having trouble in understanding how the [Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) feature can be replicated in AWS.

Specifically, we want a Jenkins job that will allow us to specify a branch name and a set of environment variables. That job will then spin up our entire stack, so that the developer can test their changes in isolation, before moving to staging.

Our stack is 5 different Ruby on Rails applications, all of which must know each other's URLs, which does complicate things.

I'm told that tools like [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) or [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) might be suitable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?